# In memory Oracle database for testing in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oracle11g

We have a Rails 4 application that connects to an Oracle database using oracle-enhanced-adapter.  Is it possible to create an in-memory database for testing?  The database was created before the Rails app, so how could I get the schema.rb file?

**Edit**: I was able to obtain the schema.rb file by creating a rake task that does the same thing as [rake db:schema:dump](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake), but specifies the connection to the legacy database instead of ActiveRecord::Base.connection.  My plan was to use sqlite3 as an in-memory database, since the setup for that is documented, but that didn't work either because the schema.rb file has some methods that aren't recognized by sqlite3 (add_foreign_key).  I still need to get an in-memory database created for testing.